How can I change the hover color of the MUI GridToolbarFilterButton options
enter image description here
enter image description here
I have been trying to change, the native select option hover color of the Native, although I couldn't.
I want the hover color of the options to align with our website's accent color, but it's currently using the default MUI colors. How can I target and style the dropdown option colors to match our company's default theme

how are you doing your theming?

For example, you could use the following CSS:
li.MuiButtonBase-root.MuiMenuItem-root.MuiMenuItem-gutters.MuiMenuItem-root.MuiMenuItem-gutters:hover {
    background-color: #777; /* this can be any color you want */
/* other styles here*/
}

